# parallel calculation where only the fastest solution "wins" C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a program that creates multiple threads (5-20) at a time to calculate iterations of a single problem in parallel. 
Now any of these threads can come up with a valid solution at which point this solution (in form of an object reference) should be reported back to the main thread to stop all other threads and create new ones based on this solution.

When a solution is found, it is critical that the main thread responds fast to stop/pause the threads and process the solution.

I've looked into the observer pattern, C++11's `std::async` methods and `std::future`/`promise` objects, but usually the examples expect a result from all the threads which are then collected and processed. 
In my application only one "winner" thread can deliver a solution, but I can't know beforehand which one it will be.

Since I'm new to parallel programming I'm wondering what the best way to implement this would be? What is the most efficient way to make the main thread wait for the result of just one out of multiple other threads/parallel tasks?

Edit to clarify:
I have a realtime signal that needs to be analysed. I have different algorithms that can determine a subset of different states of the system. The "winning" algorithm matches the signal to one of these categories so the current system state is known. Depending on the current state the system can go into different states in the future, which again need to be detected.
Currently all these algorithms run sequentially in a loop until one can find a fitting category, at which point main thread sets the parameters for the subsequent interval of detection. But with parallel computation of this different algorithms I could greatly increase efficiency.

Comment: Depends on your algorithm. You're asking something very conceptual, but there is no single "golden" solution.

Comment: If you find yourself in need of preemptively stopping threads, it's possible you haven't broken your problem down to the required granularity of "tasks".

Comment: `std::atomic<thread_id>` might be useful to show who won, and the main thread could use `std::condition_variable` to wait for a winner. However, the question is just too broad right now; perhaps you can post once you work on your algorithm a bit more?

Comment: You can not simply abort a running thread or task. The reason for this is, there is no way the compiler or program can know how to release the resources hold by the task or thread.

Comment: fork/wait/kill?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your requirements in your head a little more... What happens if 2 threads finish at roughly the same time - is it ok to take either?  Are you willing to slow down the processing fractionally so that your threads can terminate when a solution is found?  I would take a look at the std::condition_varliable; which your main thread can wait on and your worker threads can notify when done - meaning you don't need your main thread polling.

Comment: @OutOfBound That's not entirely true, it is possible using platform-specific functions, for example on POSIX systems you can use pthread_cancel. It's generally a bad idea though. Having the threads periodically check a condition variable like UKMonkey suggests would certainly be better.

Comment: I think all algorithms are going to have to regularly check an atomic flag to decide to continue or not.

Comment: @UKMonkey when 2 threads finish at roughly the same time, either would be ok. It's just important that only one of the solutions is processed, not both (or more). Also self-terminating the threads on a signal would be ok, they run in a loop anyway. I think what you are imagining is similar to the solution ComicSansMS proposed, which I will try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two things to consider here: You need a communication channel from the worker threads to the main thread to notify that a result has been computed. And you need a communication channel from the main thread to the workers to request the slower threads to abort their computation once a result was found by another thread.

Note that those two communication channels are used in different ways. The notification from the worker to the main thread is an *event*: The main thread should block until it receives the result notification from the fastest thread and then wake up and continue immediately. The notification from the main thread to the remaining workers is different: The workers are already busy performing their computation and they only check from time to time whether they should abort. So they want to perform *polling*. We furthermore want to eliminate concurrency on the communication channels as much as possible, so that we do not slow down the worker threads more than necessary.

The first kind of notification is a good match for a [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). You keep a single result buffer that is shared by all threads. As soon as a worker has completed, it locks a mutex protecting the result buffer, checks if there is already a result stored there and if not, copies its result to the buffer and notifies the `condition_variable`. The main thread waits on that same condition variable. Note that even though the threads all share the same condition variable and result buffer, there is little concurrency here, as we expect the threads to complete the computation at different times, and the main thread is actually sleeping the whole time, waiting for the notification from the condition variable.

For the polling, you can use an [`atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) variable that is shared between one worker thread and the main thread. Once the main thread has retrieved its result, it sets the atomic variables for all the workers. The workers periodically check whether their atomic variable was set and if so, abort their computation. Note that there is a trade-off here in how frequently you want to perform the polling. Poll too frequently, and you have a lot of overhead on the workers. Poll too rarely, and your workers are less responsive to the abortion request.